# There is no PWM output

Tags: pwm

I recently made a project where output is coming from the differential between data reading and reference value. It works on my Proteus simulation but there is no PWM output on my real world device.

Here is my code listing

```
for (z = 0; z <= output2; z++)
  if (output2 >= 30) {
   toggle == HIGH; 
   en = !en;
  }
if (en == true) {
  OCR1A = map(z, 0, 255, 0, ICR1); ;
  OCR1B = 0;
} else {
  OCR1A=0; 
  OCR1B = map(z, 0, 255, 0, ICR1);
}
if (output2 < 30) {
  en = !en;
  analogWrite(9, 0);
  analogWrite(10, 0);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by calling `map()`? Do you know what OCR1A/B are and how the `analogWrite()` function works?

Comment: i saw from other program that is for setting up the carrier frequency, so if icr1=1600, 0-255 = 0-10khz, cmiiw,

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish, but you’re writing a constant `0` to the analog output.

> ```
> if (output2 < 30) {
>   en = !en;
>   analogWrite(9, 0);
>   analogWrite(10, 0);
> }
> ```

To quote the [analogWrite() doc](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/)

> Syntax
>
> analogWrite(pin, value)
>
> Parameters
>
> pin: the pin to write to. Allowed data types: int.
>
> value: the duty cycle: between 0 (always off) and 255 (always on). Allowed data types: int

If you want to see an output, you have to write a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: yes it is purposely gives 0 cycle when the output is less than 30